# Handling catch exception on php

Tags: php, oop, exception, session-variables

How do I to store a exception error message in a session? I tried something like below, but the execution is interrupted with exception message and don't set my SESSION.

```
catch(MyServiceException $e) {
    $_SESSION['status']['mensagem_servidor'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm receiving a "maximum execution time error" from a curl script, the server gets busy and don't send me the response. I need to handle this message to create a customized message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the basics.

1. **MyServiceException** class should extend to \Exception. Take note of that back-slash as it refers to the base PHP Exception class.
2. Are you sure that "message" field in that class has value and not null? It's better if you var_dump the contents of that exception instance:

   `catch(MyServiceException $e) {
       var_dump($e);
       die(); // terminate here, just for debugging purposes
       $_SESSION['status']['mensagem_servidor'] = $e->getMessage();
   }`

We can help you more if you can post here, either your MyServiceException class codes, or the result of that var_dump() thing I told you.